# Periodicity of substitution system

Tags: algorithms, arrays, iteration

I’m interested in substitution systems: maps which use a set of rules to transform elements of a sequence into a new sequence.
For simplicity we will consider here only binary 1-D arrays.
Unlike the [Wolfram language definition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubstitutionSystem.html), I suppose that LHS of rule may be any length.
So a set of rules like `[[0] → [1, 0], [1, 1] → [0]]` is valid.

Let’s in one of the steps we got the periodic sequence (may be eventually periodic).
Because we only deal with finite sequences,
here I assume a naive definition of eventually periodicity:

there is such non-periodic prefix (may be empty) $P$ and such non-empty pattern $Q$ that sequence looks like $S = PQQ…$,
so the pattern is repeated at least two times. In this case, finding *the minimum period* does not matter

The question is:
Can we say that for this set of rules $R$ after its next application, the sequence will retain the periodicity property?
(Possibly with other patterns, so it'll look like $P_1Q_1Q_1…$).
I don’t think so, but I’d like to prove it.